# Error [Common 17-165] when creating IP core

Tags: xilinx, vivado

I'm trying to create an IP core in Vivado 2015.2 and followed [this guide](http://www.fpgadeveloper.com/2014/08/creating-a-custom-ip-block-in-vivado.html). When trying to edit the IP in the "Create and Package IP" screen, I'm getting the following error.

```
ipx::edit_ip_in_project -upgrade true -name edit_tiger_writeback_v1_0 -directory {C:/Users/Username/Desktop/ip_repo} {c:/Users/Username/Desktop/ip_repo/tiger_writeback_1.0/component.xml}
ERROR: [Common 17-165] Too many positional options when parsing '-force', please type 'create_project -help' for usage info.
ERROR: [Ipptcl 7-562] Cannot create project 'edit_tiger_writeback_v1_0'.
ERROR: [Common 17-39] 'ipx::edit_ip_in_project' failed due to earlier errors.
```

What does that mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Zynq-All-Programmable-SoC/ERROR-Common-17-165-Too-many-positional-options-when-parsing/td-p/509973) thread?

Answer (score 1):

I had your same errors and the problem was a space character into the path, so I moved the entire project into a new one without spaces and it worked.

Comment: The projects path `c:/Users/Username/Desktop/ip_repo/tiger_writeback_1.0/component.xml` contains no spaces; so how should this help ?

Comment: Maybe the dot  in "tiger_writeback_1.0" is too "strange" for the tcl engine.

Comment: Excellent answer. I think this was the solution for me.